# I cannot reach php built-in server running on a VM

Tags: php, virtual-machine, remote-access, php-builtin-server

I have a too basic php application that I wante to run through the built-in php server and that lives in my VM in my windows machine:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->get('/', function (Request $req, Response $res, $arg = []) {
    return 'hello world!!';
});

$app->run();
```

**My project structure**

```
tree -I vendor
.
|-- cache
|   `-- 6a
|       `-- 532bg9987gt23f4356546poo999vvb234234.php
|-- composer.json
|-- composer.lock
|-- public
|   `-- js
|       `-- app.js
|-- routes
|   `-- web.php
`-- views
    `-- templates
        `-- index.html

7 directories, 7 files
```

When I run curl from within my VM it obviously works:

```
php -S localhost:9899&
curl localhost:9899/routes/web.php

Hello world!!
```

The problem is when I try to connect to this server from my browser (windows machine) I get

```
This site can’t be reached
```

Although this doesn't work for my php built-in server, it works perfectly for two other projects developed with [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) that are on the same VM as the [php](/questions/tagged/php) one.

Why I'm not able to reach the php built-in server especially that [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) built-in server are accessible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are binding your server to `localhost`. It is only listening on the `localhost` network interface. It won't be accessible outside of that machine.

Tell it to listen on your externally facing IP address instead.

Alternatively, tell it to listen on *all* network interfaces:

```
php -S 0.0.0.0:9889
```